# publishSubscribeChannel unit test can't work well

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

my integration config class is below，when i do some unit test on them,found that:
when i send message to `UserRecipientSubscribeCacheChannel`,it work well;
when i send a message to an upper level of channel `userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel`, it work failed,and it don't throws any exceptions yet. i can't understand it. the messages that i sent is same,of course.

because of the fail section, the next handler can't work ok. 
ty!!

it work ok below, it print `===>ip location  channel message:GenericMessage [payload=[MailRecipientActionDocumen...`and `===>user recipient  channel message:GenericMessage [payload=[UserRecipientSubscribeDataRedisStructure...`

```
 @Test
public void test_sendMessageUserRecipientSubscribeCacheChannel(){
    UserRecipientSubscribeCacheChannel.send(createMessageWithIp());
}
```

it work fail below, it print `===>ip location  channel message:GenericMessage [payload=[MailRecipientActionDocumen...` only

notice that:  the fail section, In front of handler has a transformer.

```
@Test
public void test_sendMessageToRouteChannel() {
    userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel.send(createMessageWithIp());
}
```

my code config below:

```
@Bean  
public SubscribableChannel userReportWriteCompletedSubscribeChannel() {  
    return new DirectChannel();  
} 

@Bean
public QueueChannel userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel ipLocationResolveCacheChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel userRecipientSubscribeCacheChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@MessagingGateway(name = "userReportWriteCompletedListener",
        defaultRequestChannel = "userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel")
public interface UserReportWriteCompletedListener {
    @Gateway
    void receive(List<UserMailRecipientActionDocument> docs);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow bridgeFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.channel("userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel")
            .bridge(bridgeSpe -> bridgeSpe
                    .poller(pollerFactory -> pollerFactory.fixedRate(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))

            .channel("userReportWriteCompletedSubscribeChannel")
            ;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow subscribeFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("userReportWriteCompletedSubscribeChannel")
            .publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
                    .subscribe(flow -> flow
                            .channel(IP_LOCATION_RESOLVE_CACHE_CHANNEL)
                    )
                    .subscribe(flow -> flow
                            .channel(USER_RECIPIENT_SUBSCRIBE_CACHE_CHANNEL)
                    ))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler ipLocationResolveCacheHandler(RedisTemplate<String, ?> redisTemplate) {
    final RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler ipLocationResolveCacheHandler =
            new RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler(redisTemplate);
    ipLocationResolveCacheHandler.setKey("IP_LOCATION_RESOLVE_CACHE");
    return ipLocationResolveCacheHandler;
}

@Bean
public RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler userRecipientSubscribeCacheHandler(RedisTemplate<String, ?> redisTemplate) {
    final RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler userRecipientSubscribeCacheHandler =
            new RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler(redisTemplate);
    userRecipientSubscribeCacheHandler.setKey("USER_RECIPIENT_SUBSCRIBE_CACHE");
    return userRecipientSubscribeCacheHandler;
}

@Bean
public IpLocationResolveRedisStructureFilterAndTransformer recipientActionHasIpFilterAndTransformer() {
    return new IpLocationResolveRedisStructureFilterAndTransformer();
}

@Bean
public UserRecipientSubscribeDataRedisStructureTransformer subscribeDataRedisStructureTransformer(
        IpLocationClient ipLocationClient) {
    return new UserRecipientSubscribeDataRedisStructureTransformer(ipLocationClient);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ipLocationResolveCacheFlow(
        @Qualifier("ipLocationResolveCacheHandler") RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler writingMessageHandler) {
    return flow -> flow.channel(IP_LOCATION_RESOLVE_CACHE_CHANNEL)
            .handle(message -> {
                System.out.println("===>ip location  channel message:" + message);
            })

            ;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow userRecipientActionDataCacheFlow(
        @Qualifier("userRecipientSubscribeCacheHandler") RedisStoreWritingMessageHandler messageHandler,
        UserRecipientSubscribeDataRedisStructureTransformer transformer) {
    return flow -> flow.channel(USER_RECIPIENT_SUBSCRIBE_CACHE_CHANNEL)
            .transform(transformer)
                   .handle(message -> {
                System.out.println("===>user recipient  channel message:" + message);
            })      
}
```

i expect 2 print message info ,but print 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Today, i found that the bridge flow may had some problem, When I move the handler behind the channel`userReportWriteCompletedSubscribeChannel`, it can't print any message;
when i remove channel and add handler directly, it will print message.
does i use the bridge wrong?

```
   @Bean
public IntegrationFlow bridgeFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.channel("userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel")
            .bridge(bridgeSpe -> bridgeSpe
                    .poller(pollerFactory -> pollerFactory.fixedRate(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .handle(message -> {
                System.out.println("===>route  channel message:" + message);
            })   // handle ok ,  will print message
            .channel("userReportWriteCompletedSubscribeChannel")
            // .handle(message -> {
            //    System.out.println("===>route  channel message:" + message);
            // })       // handle fail ,  will not printing message
            ;
}
```

test:

```
    @Test
//invalid
public void test_sendMessageToRouteChannel() {
    userReportWriteCompletedRouteChannel.send(createMessageWithIp());
}
```